# Integration of Bessel function multiplied with an algebraic and trigonometric functions.

Tags: integral-equations

I tried my best to solve the following definite integration.
[image]

Struggling a lot, ended with no luck. I know similar but a bit little simplified identity.  [image]

The question is how to change this identity for my case which include two extra constants or how to solve this integral in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute
$$I=\int_0^X  J_1( \alpha t)\,e^{-b t^2}\,dt$$

As you did, let $\alpha t=x$ to make
$$I={\frac 1 \alpha}\int_0^{ \alpha X} J_1( x)\,e^{-\beta x^2}\,dx \qquad \text{with}\qquad \beta=\frac{b}{\alpha^2 }$$

Now, use the expansion
$$ J_1( x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m }{m! \,2^{2 m+1} \, \Gamma (m+2)}x^{2 m+1}$$ which makes that you face now the problem of 
$$K_m=\int x^{2 m+1}\,e^{-\beta x^2}\,dx=-\frac{ \Gamma \left(m+1, \beta x^2\right) }{2\beta ^{(m+1)}} \,$$ and 
$$L_m=\int_0^{ \alpha X} x^{2 m+1}\,e^{-\beta x^2}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (m+1)-\Gamma \left(m+1,{ \beta \alpha ^2}X^2\right) }{2 \beta ^{m+1} }$$

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici, I will try to solve like this but if in case I found some issues I will get in touch to you.

Comment: @UbaidUllah. You are welcome ! If you think it is good, may be, you could accept my answer in order other people know that is a possible solution. Cheers.

Comment: Great Claude Leibovici, Your answer solve my problem. There is a typo "The upper limit of integral is $$ \alpha x$$" and the answer confuses x with X.

Comment: @UbaidUllah. Sorry for the typo !